# Write a function to remove a character from a list?

Tags: python, list

I need to write my own function that will accept a list, and if the list contains the specified character, said character will be removed. Here's what I have.

```
def deleteElement(self,x):
    length = len(self.elements)
    print length
    for i in range(length):
        if (self.elements[i] == x):
            del self.elements[i]
```

However, this keeps generating an index out of bounds error, but I'm not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: Probably because your list has duplicates, so your index needs to change by 1 each time you successfully remove an element. Think about it.

Comment: `length = len(self.elements)` will always give you an index out of bounds. A list like `[1,2]` would have `len` of `2` but no index of 2

Comment: @Cfreak that's not the reason, he is iterating from `range(length)` which goes from `0 to length-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you are careful of keeping track of how many items have been deleted, and adjusting your index accordingly:

```
In [91]: def deleteElement(elements,x):
    ...:     offset = 0
    ...:     length = len(elements)
    ...:     for i in range(length):
    ...:         if  elements[i - offset] == x:
    ...:             del elements[i - offset]
    ...:             offset += 1
    ...:

In [92]: elements = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

In [93]: deleteElement(elements, 1)

In [94]: elements
Out[94]: [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Can I suggest a different method?
def deleteElement(self,x):
    self.elements = [e for e in self.elements if e!=x]
```

Answer (score 0):

the golden rule says, do not modify a list while you are looping in it. You may use a copy if necessarily :

```
def deleteElement(self,x):
    length = len(self.elements)
    temp = self.elements[:]
    print length
    for i in range(length):
        if (self.elements[i] == x):
            del temp[i]
    self.elements = temp[:]
```